# Updating ArrayLists that contains each other?

Tags: java

Apologies if there have been similar questions, I'm honestly not sure how to call this concept to search for questions.

So I need to create a database with 3 classes like below:

```
public class Actor {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Movie> movies; //all movies the actor has been in
}

public class Movie {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Actor> actors;
}

public class MovieDatabase {
    private ArrayList<Movie> movieList;
    private ArrayList<Actor> actorList; //all actors in the movie
}
```

I have to create a method to add a movie and an actor to the database.
The final goals is that the new movie needs to be of the Movie class, and contains all the actors that are in it, same for the new actor.

What I cannot figure out is that, since the Movie class contains an array of Actor objects, and the Actor class contains an array of Movie list, how do you update so that in the end, the new Movie added contains a complete list of Actors in it, with each Actor in the list having their movie lists updated with the new Movie object?

Is recursion the right concept to apply in this case?

Comment: Are you looking to use an actual database, or is the question just about the MovieDatabase class you've created?

Comment: The classes Actor and Movies should have setters so that while updating Movies, you can update for every actor set the movie to him.

Comment: @Rick sorry I probably worded it incorrectly, I was referring to the MovieDatabase class

Comment: @SabareeshMuralidharan Thanks, but wouldn't the movie being added not be complete? Since when the new Movie is first created, the list of Actors in it will be blank. If it is added to the list of movies of the actor, it will not actually be a completed Movie object right? I feel like afterwards it would fall into an endless loop of updating the Movie with Actors, then updating the Actors with the revised Movie, then updating the Movie again with the revised Actors, and so on

Comment: See when there is no point of completion it would be a race, but here you can start with a movie object update. Update it's movie name and while fetching the actors check if a particular actor is already present. If yes, update this movie to his list. If no, create a new actor and update this movie to him/her

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a new Movie gets added

```
Movie movie = new Movies();

movie.setActors(listOfActors)
```

Now for each actor you need to update the movie list

```
listOfActors.forEach(actor -> addMovieToActor(movie,actor));


public addMovieToActor(Movie movie,Actor actor){

   List<Movies> existingMovies =actor.getMovies();

   existingMovies.add(movie);
}
```

Depending on your needs, you may need to take care of synchronization between updates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think my problem is with the synchronization. How do you actually synchronize, so that the new Movie being added to the Movie List will contains a list of Actors whose Movie list has been updated with that same new Movie?

Comment: I don't think you can do it in one shot. one will be updated after the other. Something has to come first. The movie or an actor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think recursion is appropriate here, although you *could* use it. The databases have a circular dependency so you just need to synchronize after updates. In other words, make sure that after you add a new entry, both databases are updated with the missing information. Synchronization can be made easier by swapping `ArrayList` out for a `HashMap`, you may need to refactor your classes to do this. I left out the lists for simplicity, you can add them in as a parameter:

```
void update(String movieName, String actorName) {
    if (movies.get(movieName) == null) {
        movies.put(movieName);
    } 
    if (actors.get(actorName) == null) {
        actors.put(actorName);
    }
}
```

Use as:

```
HashMap<String> actors = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String> movies = new HashMap<>();
actors.put("foo");
movies.put("bar");
// Update happened, synchronize with what you just added
update("foo", "bar");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Circular dependency is the keyword I was looking for, so really thanks for that. Unfortunately it is required that I use ArrayList.